# PDO: Multiple commands in PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND

Tags: php, pdo

i'm using this PDO connection:

```
try{

$db=new PDO("
mysql:host=localhost;
dbname=...",
"dbu...",
"pass",
array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET lc_time_names='de_DE'"));
}
catch(PDOException $e){die("Error!");}
```

Now i would like to add another init command:

```
array(
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET lc_time_names='de_DE'",
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
)
```

But it looks like that the utf8-one overwrites the first init command.

So i've tried this one but also without success:

```
array(
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => array("SET lc_time_names='de_DE'","SET NAMES utf8")
)
```

Any idea how to send more than just one init command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

PDO doesn't support multiple `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND` options. However, in case you need to execute multiple `SET` commands, you can use a workaround:

```
array
(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET lc_time_names='de_DE',NAMES utf8"
)
```

From [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-statement.html):

> A SET statement can contain multiple variable assignments, separated by commas.

Note that regarding the `SET NAMES` command, it is the [recommended](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php#example-1419) to use the `charset` DSN option instead.

Comment: you saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Far from intuitive (i've been trying to add multiple semicolon separated queries...) thus very helpful answer.

Answer (score -5):

1. You don't need it. Everything you're trying to put in `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND` **doesn't belong there.** That's not whatever "init commands" but just regular SQL queries that can be merely run usual way after connect.
2. Regarding `SET NAMES` particular query, you shouldn't be using it either way, as you should set encoding through DSN.

Thus, your code should be

```
$db=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=...;charset=utf8","dbu...","pass");
$db->query("SET lc_time_names='de_DE'");
$db->query("whatever else SQL you have fancy to run");
```

Note that there shouldn't be anything like `catch(PDOException $e){die("Error!");}` as well

Comment: It is not a solution. `PDO` does not automatically connect in __construct. But your query is executed only once. If PDO looses connection it reconnects and the session has the default values again.

Comment: @iRaS that's a strange idea of yours. PDO doesn't "reconnect" by itself. Where did you get that?